# CSS 3 dynamic columns, same width align top

Tags: html, css

**My JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3YGdL/

**My CSS:**

```
#sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#sidebar div {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar-left {
    background-color: green;
}

#sidebar-center {
    background-color: red;
}

#sidebar-right {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#sidebar li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

**My Question:**

I want the 3 columns in one line with exactly the same width and aligned top. The content of those 3 columns should be dynamic, this means, the height should automatic change to the max height. We never know which of the 3 columns is the highest one, so this should be dynamic too.

My current solution is in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YGdL/), I've tried other stuff like "display: table" but this was even worse...

[I've tried this, but it didn't work for me...](http://www.thoughtspacedesigns.com/blog/web-design-tutorials/beautiful-dynamic-3-column-css-layout/)

Comment: I'm quite sure you can't do this with pure CSS, you need some Javascript to give all 3 columns the same height width dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pure CSS [**solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/3YGdL/16/)

The HTML sturcture is the same, only i altered few lines in your CSS. I assigned **#sidebar** ***display*** to **table**.

Then, assigned **#sidebar>div** to **display** as the **table-cell** for equal height to all columns. For improving form UI i added this code

```
div.form-group input, div.form-group textarea {
    clear:both !important;
    float:none;
    margin:5px;
    display:block;
}
```

For futher details refer this [**URL**](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-equal-height/)

Hope this will be useful

Comment: **Amazing**, exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much, *I've updated the fiddle to my needs (http://jsfiddle.net/3YGdL/19/)*

Answer (score 1):

is this what you looking for?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3YGdL/1/)**

please remember that `display:inline-block` by default is baseline so you have to set it `vertical-align:top`, plus inline-block create whitespaces, you can see solutions for that here:

**[INLINE-BLOCK FIXES](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

**UPDATE**

now that i read carefully your question I understand you want same height for 3 columns, so I give you a link with some methods to achieve that:

**[Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)**

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, but why is the contact form destroyed and how can I fix this?

Comment: sorry due to timezones I wasn't able to reply you sooner. I wasn't aware that you wanted your contact form fixed as well since you didn't mentioned on your question ( I thought it was only about the columns)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a simple jQuery Script: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3YGdL/2/)

First I gave every section a class `.column` to target them more easily.

Then I get the height of every element, and apply the highest height to all of them.

```
heightArrayHeading = [];
$('.column').each(function() {
    $(this).css('height', '');
    heightArrayHeading.push($(this).outerHeight());
});

$('.column').css('height', Math.max.apply(Math, heightArrayHeading));
```

Finally I gave `.column` `vertical-align:top;` to align them on top.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, but why is the contact form destroyed and how can I fix this?